# How do i display the result row wise when td contains span and g tag etc

Tags: selenium

I have 7 rows, when clicking on it, its open one popup and that popup may contain no of rows(its dynamic)

`//div[@id='modelcontent']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr`  --- Its giving me total no of rows of a particular popup(table).
The code of one particular popup(table) is as follow:

```
<tr xpath="1">
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #5180BE"></td>
<td style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bolder; color: #5180BE; text-align:center;">
**ACTUAL**
</td>
<td style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bolder; color: #5180BE; text-align:center;"></td>
</tr>
<tr xpath="2">
<td style="font-size: 10pt; color: #333; width: 100px;">
**<span class="lobnamedecorator">
Manager
</span>**
</td>
<td style="padding-right: 10px;">
<svg width="100%" height="40" version="1.1" id="SVG_9494801b-536e-4f3d-9494-651d917b1f9d" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left:10px;">
<g>
<defs></defs>
<rect y="12" width="100%" height="25" style="stroke-width:1;stroke: #B3B3B3" fill="url(#9494801b-536e-4f3d-9494-651d917b1f9d)"></rect>
<text x="10" y="24" alignment-baseline="central" fill="black" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;">
**30%**
</text>
</g>
<g>
<line id="ls" x1="30%" y1="12" x2="30%" y2="37" style="stroke:darkorange; stroke-width:2" stroke-dasharray="4, 4"></line>
<text x="30%" y="10" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" text-anchor="middle">
**30%**
</text>
</g>
</svg>
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;">
16357/53434
</td>
<td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;">
0
</td>
</tr>
<tr xpath="3"></tr>
<tr xpath="4"></tr>
<tr xpath="5"></tr>
```

With the following code getting correct output but not getting row wise.

```
for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfRows.size();j++)
      { 
                String rowValues = totalNoOfRows.get(j).getText();                  
                System.out.format("%15s",rowValues);
        }
```

But it displays the output as below:
PASS  ACTUAL  TARGET /// It displays as first row which is correct

```
Manager
30%
30%
16357/53434 0

Employee
57%
0%
11/19 0

Non-Employee
26%
25%
2273/8544 0

Admin
38%
39%
10375/27099 0
```

But i want  to have  output as(PASS  ACTUAL TO TARGET) Row wise  same as for first row, code does not printing other values in a row.
Some of td contains span and g tag, that may be reason. Then how do i fetch all values row wise? 
My requirement to have a output as below:

```
PASS                            ACTUAL           TARGET
Manager         30%     30%     16357/57434         0
Employee        57%     0%      11/19               0
Non-Employe     23%     12%     17/59               0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the break lines in your string:

```
for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfRows.size();j++){ 
    String rowValues = totalNoOfRows.get(j).getText();                  
    System.out.println(rowValues.replace("\n", " "));
}
```

Comment: I tried but here 'rowValues' is a string, it does not give any method like replace.

Comment: @Appi String always have the replace method. You've tried the above approach?